# UIButton setImage is not working

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to set the UIImage for a UIButton via the following code, but nothing happens. I am setting these inside viewDidLoad. The only way it shows up is if I use storyboard and set the image that way.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  ...

     [self.locateMeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(11, 11, 46, 46)];
     [self.locateMeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locateme_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
     [self.locateMeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locateme_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
     [self.locateMeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locateme_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  ...

 }
```

Comment: type is not defined here. roundrect or Custom button?

Comment: Is it nil, by any chance?

Comment: Found issue. Somehow Xcode didn't make the connection to the viewcontroller when I crontrol dragged to the VC. It created the IBOutlet but didn't make the connection (right clicking the button in storyboard showed no connections)?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *aboutBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[aboutBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showAboutPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aboutBtn setTitle:@"About Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aboutBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 120.0, 162.0, 42.0)];
[aboutBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locateme_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aboutBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locateme_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out in my case that I was recreating the toolbar so the wrong toolbar object was being used. (Was trying to access a button on the wrong toolbar). Basically it seems a good idea to just check systematically that your methods are acting on all the receivers you expect and are being passed parameter values that you would expect.